# change [...] text in wordpress posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using this PHP to display Wordpress blog posts on an external website:

```
<?php
$posts = get_posts('numberposts=10&order=DESC&orderby=post_date');
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        setup_postdata( $post );
        ?><h2><a href="/blog/<?php echo $post->post_name; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2><br>
        Posted on <?php the_date(); ?><br><br>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        <br><hr /><br>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

how can i change the `[...]` at the end of the excerpt to be `[Read More]` ?

Comment: Search in Google for "excerpt wordpress ellipsis", first result!

Answer (score 1):

Copy this code into your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
function new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return '[Read more]';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

Or if you want to put post's link on the text:

```
function new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return ' <a class="read-more" href="'. get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '">Read More</a>';
 }
 add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more' );
```